# Rest API call Request returning null

Tags: c#, json, rest, restsharp

Using RestSharp, want to make a simple call to this API: https://dbd.tricky.lol/api/characters

Specifically, I want one of the characters as an object in my C# Program. Here's the call:

```
var options = new RestClientOptions("https://dbd.tricky.lol/api");
var client = new RestClient(options);
var response = await client.GetJsonAsync<Killers>("characters?id=Chuckles");
```

And Here is the Model I want to deserialize to:

```
public int _id { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
public string gender { get; set; }
public string tunables { get; set; }
public string difficulty { get; set; }
public string height { get; set; }
```

The response always ends up being null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try putting the generated JSON through https://json2csharp.com?

Comment: I posted a working solution below. Let me know if you have issues. I tested this working, so I am confident it will get you what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually read the API doc and call the right URL. also your model is incorrect. Here is the correct version of your code

```
var options = new RestClientOptions("https://dbd.tricky.lol/api");
var client = new RestClient(options);
var response = await client.GetJsonAsync<Killer>("characterinfo?character=Chuckles");

public class Killer
{
    public int index { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string alias {get;set;}
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string difficulty { get; set; }
    public string height { get; set; }
    public Tunables tunables {get;set;}
}

public class Tunables
{
    public int maxwalkspeed {get;set;}
    public int terrorradius {get;set;}
    public int basebeartrapcarrycapacity {get;set;}
}
```

This produces the following :

[image]

I didn't add all the class variables for this as you can go through and do that, but this completes the request from your question above.

Comment: tested this working, so should be correct answer.